# ¿Como convertir campos de una columna de tipo int en Sql Server a varchar al momento de ser visibles?

Tags: sql-server, conversión-de-tipos

Ya tengo creada una tabla dentro de mi base de datos en SQL Server, con su respectiva vista también. Tengo un campo de esa tabla llamado "Mes" de tipo entero, mi objetivo es que al momento de ingresar 1 dentro de los inserts al momento de ejecutar el select de mi tabla o vista aparezca la palabra "Enero" indicando el nombre del mes y no el número que ingrese en un principio. Lo mismo aplicaría para los demás meses, 2 = "Febrero", 3 = "Marzo" etc...

De antemano gracias por alguna respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No existe nada preestablecido que regrese el nombre del mes desde un entero. Lo que existe es algo que regresa el nombre del mes de una fecha. Es importante notar que la configuración de lenguaje debe ser la correcta. Por otro lado, también se puede generar una expresión `CASE` para regresar la cadena que se busca.

```
SELECT mes, 
    -- Usando CASE
    CASE mes 
        WHEN  1 THEN 'Enero'
        WHEN  2 THEN 'Febrero'
        WHEN  3 THEN 'Marzo'
        WHEN  4 THEN 'Abril'
        WHEN  5 THEN 'Mayo'
        WHEN  6 THEN 'Junio'
        WHEN  7 THEN 'Julio'
        WHEN  8 THEN 'Agosto'
        WHEN  9 THEN 'Septiembre'
        WHEN 10 THEN 'Octubre'
        WHEN 11 THEN 'Noviembre'
        WHEN 12 THEN 'Diciembre' END,
    --Usando DATENAME
    DATENAME( MM, DATEFROMPARTS(1,mes,1))
FROM(VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12))x(mes)
```